# Convergence in $L^{\infty}$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that for $f \in L^{\infty}$ we have, $$ || \tau_y f - f||_{\infty}  \to 0$$ as $y \to 0$ where $\tau_y = f(x-y)$. Does convergence in $L^{\infty}$ imply that, $$ \lim_{y \to 0 } |f(x-y) - f(x)| = 0$$ or $$ \lim_{y \to 0} \inf_{x \in X} |f(x-y) -f(x) | =0$$

Comment: What is this $X$ you speak of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes to both questions. This follows from the inequalities
$$
\inf_x \left\lvert f(x-y)-f(x)\right\rvert \le \left\lvert f(x_0-y)-f(x_0)\right\rvert\le \sup_x \left\lvert f(x-y)-f(x)\right\rvert=\|\tau_yf-f\|_\infty, $$
which hold for any $x_0$ and any $y$.

Comment: Does this imply that $f$ is uniformly continuous outside of a set of measure zero? It seems like it should if $\lim_{y \to 0} \sup_{x \in x} |f(x-y) - f(x)| =0$

Comment: @Yuugi: Yes, this is exactly a reformulation of the uniform continuity property. I think that $\|\tau_y f-f\|_\infty$ is usually called *modulus of continuity*.